# Concatenating file paths while overriding window file name length problem

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, glob

I am having problems with the concatenation of a server directory path using python 3.7. I have it working but need to bring in this code (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31474059/11515528)) so as to override the max 260 character limit on windows director paths.

```
\\\\?\\UNC
```

Just can't seem to get the syntax-correct. The function below is working (brings back matches) without the UNC added. But when it hits a long filename it crashes the program.

```
def file_path(data):
    latest_file_list = []
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        log1 = row['Log number 2001']
        file_path = row['file_path_short']
        location = r"" +str(file_path)+ "*\*\*\*\**\*"+ str(log1) +"*.pdf"
        # check file on drive
        list_of_files = glob.glob(location, recursive=True)
```

location equates to:

```
\\servername\...
```

The code below is what I am testing to fix the character limit, it does not give an error but also does not return any matches.

```
location2 = r"\\\\?\\UNC" +str(file_path)+ "*\*\*\*\**\**\*"+ str(log1) +"*.pdf"
```

location2 equates to

```
\\?\UNC\servername\...
```

I have tried prefixing with u and r but that does not help.

Can anyone give some guidance please? Is there a better/simpler solution?

**Edit**

I have also tried this which works for short file names but gives [WinError 3] error for long file names.

```
import os
location3 = os.path.join(r"\\\\?\\UNC", str(file_path), "*\*\**", "*"+ str(log1) +"*" +".pdf" )
```

**Edit2**

So I have been playing around with pathlib using this code:

```
from pathlib import Path
location4 = Path(r"\\\\?\\UNC", str(file_path), "*\*\**", "*"+ str(log1) +"*" +".pdf" )
```

But I am getting this error currently `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: Have you tried using Python3's builting pathlib? https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: @Hrabal I have tried os.path.join but could not seem to get that working.

Answer (score 0):

So the way I got this working, in the end, was to use a mapped file path. I have the network drive I am accessing mapped to my Z drive. I used this code to access it. It works fine just I have to make sure I have accessed the drive first before running the code.

```
location = "\\\\?\\Z:" +str(file_path)+ "*\*\*\*\**\*"+ str(log1) +"*.pdf"
```

So I have moved from `\\server\folder1\folder2\foldere3..` to `Z:\foldere2\foldere3..` so when concatenated together `\\\\?\\Z:\folder2\folder3..`